# Cannot vote at all, but can edit / tag etc.

Tags: support, voting

I cannot seem to vote on Superuser. I can on Stackoverflow however.

Error log in Firefox says `Error: vote is not defined`.

Comment: First step with all Firefox bugs: what plugins are you running?

Comment: Have you tried with other browsers?

Comment: Wasn't the plugins, it was the cache.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the JS is messed up in your browser cache.  Flush your browser cache and reload, see if that fixes it for you.